# Css Moving Controls inside another control

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, position

I have few controls side by side and I have to give position absolute to first control as a hack for sure. When I select dropdown list other controls merge inside the dropdown. How can I stop merginf the right control merge in left control after selecting dropdown list.

[This is what I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/RK6EF/34/)

```
<div>    
<div class="outer" style="display:inline;">  
       <select id="myselect" style="width:100px;">
           <option>abc</option>
           <option>def</option>
           <option>ghi</option>
           <option>jkl</option>
          <option>abc</option>
           <option>def</option>
           <option>ghi</option>
           <option>jkl</option>

    </select>
</div>
    <div style="display:inline;">Enter Details</div>
</div>
<div class="inner">Enter Name</div>
   <div class="inner">Enter Class</div>

</div>
```

Comment: if you are going to use position absolute, you are going to have to positions it, that is left:50px; for example.

Comment: What is the behavior you're expecting to see? What are you trying to make this do? Because right now deleting your JS makes the dropdown function as you're requesting.

Comment: I am doing this to implement a scrolable dropdown which is binded inside a div.